# Split the string with delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, split, apache-commons

I have a `String` as `param1=HUvguys83789r8====` i have to split this with `=` delimiter. I have tried with `String.split("=")` as well as i have used `StringUtils` too but i cannot split it correctly. Can some one help me out for this.

```
String parameters = "param1=HUvguys83789r8===="
String[] string = StringUtils.split(parameters, "=");
parameters.split("=");
```

And i got my output as `[param1, HUvguys83789r8]`

I need the output as `[param1, HUvguys83789r8====]`

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @ashokramcse what do you expect

Comment: whatever you are getting is correct only, its splitting at `=`

Comment: I expect HUvguys83789r8==== as output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really only want to split on the first occurrence of `=`, so do that

```
parameters.split("=", 2)
```

The overloaded `split(String, int)` javadoc states

> **If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied
>   at most n - 1 times**, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [String#indexOf(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) like so,

```
private static String[] splitParam(String in) {
  int p = in.indexOf('=');
  if (p > -1) {
    String key = in.substring(0, p);
    String value = in.substring(p + 1);
    return new String[] {key, value};
  }
  return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String parameters = "param1=HUvguys83789r8====";
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitParam(parameters)));
}
```

Output is

```
[param1, HUvguys83789r8====]
```

Comment: +1 for a simple solution, that can be understood when returning to the code in six months.

Comment: @Java1 what looks simple in this ? imo split was simpler

Comment: @aelor `split` is easy, and the accepted answer is just fine.  I just have a problem with ppl using hard to remember regex when a simple solution exists.  Six months later, 'ah heck, what does `\\w=\\w` mean again'

Answer (score 2):

Just split once using the alternate version of [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
String[] strings = parameters.split("=", 2); // specify max 2 parts
```

---

Test code:

```
String parameters = "param1=HUvguys83789r8====";
String[] strings = parameters.split("=",2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

Output:

```
[param1, HUvguys83789r8====]
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need :

```
    String parameters = "param1=HUvguys83789r8====";
    String[] string = parameters.split("\\w=\\w");
    String part1 = string[0]; // param
    String part2 = string[1]; // Uvguys83789r8====
    System.out.println(part1);
    System.out.println(part2);
```

make sure to escape the slashes to make it java compliant

Comment: Can you post your answer more clear since .split(/\w=\w/) it was not clear

Comment: @ashokramcse updated the answer to make it more clear